# Authenticating and Running a CL Program that uses GitHubAPI

Tags: github, github-api

So I'm trying to use this library here https://github.com/joeyh/github-backup which you run from the CL using github-backup.

My problem is that it keeps limiting my requests since I haven't authenticated with the GitHub API. Is there a way that I can authenticate and then call this program? As far as I can tell the program itself doesn't allow you to pass in authentication credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their README: "github-backup does not log into git, so it cannot backup private repositories."

That said, you could use a different tool which does allow for authentication. I forked and updated a previous (python, sorry it isn't haskell) script to use version 3 of the GitHub API and it allows for authentication. You can clone the fork [here](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/ghsync). If you set the git variables (i.e., `git config ...`) `github.user` and `github.token`, the script will handily pick them up. It's not the best user experience, but it works.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't catch that. I read through the README probably 10 times. I'll check out that repo you mentioned. Python is definitely better in my books then haskell so that's a plus too. Thanks.

Comment: Should also have mentioned that you could easily write something to do this on your own using github3.py (which powers the script I linked to). Also there's a tag for that library here on StackOverflow and questions asked there will be answered promptly (by me).